# Retrieving every Active Directory attribute using PHP

Tags: php, active-directory

In PHP, I'm building a function that adds a user into our Active Directory.  I want to compare one the entries we have in the Active Directory already, so I can figure out what info I need to include in the addUser function.

I've tried:

```
$results = ldap_search($ad, $adDN, $filter, $attr);
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ad, $results);
print_r($entries);
```

`$filter` is a username and `$attr` is empty, but it only returns the user's DN (Distinguished Name), and that's it. If I start adding things to `$attr` it will return those things added.

How can I just return every attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to return every attribute:

```
$attr = array('*');
```

Comment: Will this include operational attriutes too? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
$results = ldap_search($ad, $adDN, $filter);
```

Leave the attributes field empty.

This will not specify any attributes to pull, which means LDAP will pull every attribute.

From the manual of [`ldap_search();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php)

> **attributes**
>
> An array of the required attributes, e.g. array("mail", "sn", "cn"). Note that the "dn" is always returned irrespective of
>   which attributes types are requested.
>
> **Using this parameter is much more efficient than the default action
>   (which is to return all attributes and their associated values). The
>   use of this parameter should therefore be considered good practice.**

Comment: I realize this, but I need to keep the $attr. I made a searchAD function that associates each search with the DN of the AD, so other functions rely on using it. `$attr = array('*');` seems to do the trick